# Вывод целого числа из строки

Tags: java, строки

Как вывести первое встречающееся целое число и следующую за ним букву. Например ‘а6hdkfh54a’ выводит ‘6h’

Comment: можно посимвольно перебирать и проверять, можно через регулярное выражение. А что именно не получается?

Answer (score 0):

Можно так через регулярное выражение:

```
public static String F1(String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d\\w").matcher(input);
    if(m.find()) {
        return m.group();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // или return null;
    }
}
```